# is redirecting standard library log to logrus thread safe

Tags: go, logging, thread-safety

I am using [logrus](https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus) library for structured logging in my Go project.

I have configured my logrus as below:

```golang
// Global variable for logging
var gLog = &Logger{moduleName: ModuleName, logrus: logrus.New()}

type Logger struct {
    moduleName string
    logrus     *logrus.Logger
}

func SetupGlobalLogger(logPrefix string, logMode string) error {
    if logMode == "file" {
        logFilePath := fmt.Sprintf("var/%s.log", vite.Environment())

        file, err := os.OpenFile(logFilePath, logFileFlags, logFilePermission)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        gLog.logrus.SetOutput(file)

        // redirect logs written using standard log library to same place as logrus
        log.SetOutput(gLog.logrus.Writer())

        log.Println(vite.MarkInfo, "redirect log to file:", logFilePath)
    }

    return nil
}
```

In this Go project, there are several places where standard log library statements like `log.Println()` are used.

I want to redirect those log messages to logrus.

For that I am using following statement in above code.

```
log.SetOutput(gLog.logrus.Writer())
```

My question is: Is this thread safe?

If one thread/go-routine is executing log.Println() while another executing gLog.logrus.Info() or something on logrus, will that be fine?

Comment: https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus#thread-safety

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is Logrus Thread-safe?

[Yes](https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus#thread-safety):

> ### Thread safety
>
> By default, Logger is protected by a mutex for concurrent writes.

Except [when it isn't](https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+race).

Most of the non-thread-safe cases are bugs which will occur only in rare situations. Whether any of them matter to you depends, of course, on your use case.

Comment: Hey @Flimzy, I have a question here, does logrus uses goroutines to log or it does on the main thread internally?

Comment: @Fayaz: There's not really such a thing as a "main thread" in Go.  But as for Logrus, it uses whichever goroutines you use, at least for most operations.

Comment: I come from Android background, that's why I used the term `main thread`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Fayaz: I understand. But goroutines and threads are actually very different. Thinking about "threads" in Go is a quick way to confuse yourself :)

Comment: Yeah, I was in the thought like, let's say I am writing a mirco-service and it does some operations and if I log it on the same goroutine whichever the micro-service is running, maybe there is some millis or nanos delay and if I can launch it on other goroutine, it will save that time and user is happy too. :)

Comment: Well, your microservice isn't likely running "in a goroutine".  It's probably using (at least) one goroutine per request. That's the default (in fact, only) behavior of the standard library's HTTP server, for example.